# SSH Reverse Connection

Tags: ssh, client

I want to know, is there any way to do something like reverse SSH? I've read about such thing but I'm not sure if that is what I want.

What I want is a connection between my 'server' and my 'client', the client logs on to the server and using the server to control the client. I've made a little script for it using Python to do the basic things using socket programming, but due to my programming skills I'm not able to do advanced stuff such as the things SSH can offer you.

So the scenario is: I want to be able to control the client from the server. I make sure the client connects to the server, and with the server I control the client. So the connecting is reverse, the rest is just normal. Is this possible? Is this ever made or is it a dumb duplicate?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry guys, it is indeed described all over the internet.

So what you have to do:
In my case, on my 'client':
`ssh -f -N -R 7000:localhost:22 [username]@[server-ip]`
Where ofcourse `ssh` is your program 
`-f` means you run requests at the background
`-N` means that you don't want to execute a command, but forwarding ports.
`-R` means you want to use reverse SSH as described in the question above. Furthermore, `7000:localhost:22` makes it possible that any connection to port `7000` will be redirected to `localhost:22` where `localhost` is the client, and `22` is the client's port. 
Last but not least, you need to replace `[username]` with the username of the server, and `[server-ip]` with the server's IP-address.

Next, run on the server:
`ssh [username]@localhost -p 7000`
Where you need to replace `[username]` with the username of the client. It's the username of the client, because although it seems you are logging into your `localhost`, your `localhost` just forwards the connection asked on port `7000` to the client.
 So the `-p 7000` specifies the port where to connect to, which is the same as the one we specified in our previous command.